# взаимодействие php - ajax проблема с передачей строк

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

при обновлении записи в табл
полностью игнорируются все значения кроме десятичных цифр
то есть запрос типа [https://домен/скрипт.php?id=4&question=234567&answer=234567](https://%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD/%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82.php?id=4&question=234567&answer=234567)
проходит без проблем - запись в бд ведётся, но если заменить 234567 на строку, без разницы выделяя кавычками или нет, запись просто игнорируется
логи пустые

php

```
$question = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["question"]);
$answer = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["answer"]);
$idq = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["id"]);
$query = "UPDATE ИМЯТАБЛИЦЫ SET QUESTION=".$question.", ANSWER=".$answer." WHERE ID =".$idq ;
mysql_query($query);
```

ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url:  "editq.php",
    data: "id="+id+"&question="+question+"&answer="+answer,
    cache: false
})
```

data пробовал следующими способами:
1)

```
data:{
"id": id,
"question": question,
"&answer": answer
}
```

2)

```
data: "id='"+id+"'&question="+question+"'&answer='"+answer+"'"
```

3)

```
data: "{id:'"+id+"','question':"+question+",'answer':"+answer+"}"
```

и самое интересное - где именно ошибка понять не могу:
либо не так передаю, либо неправильно записываю

Тип поля в бд - text, пробовал и с кавычками и без кавычек!

Comment: А тип поля в таблице БД проверить не судьба?

Comment: @Эдуард , пробовал и с кавычками и без. тип поля текстовый, потому и показываю jquery ))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если переменные не пустые, в базу все хорошо идет

```
$question = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["question"]);
$answer = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["answer"]);
$idq = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["id"]);
$query = "UPDATE `ИМЯТАБЛИЦЫ` SET `QUESTION`='{$question}', `ANSWER`='{$answer}' WHERE `ID` = {$idq};";
mysql_query($query);
```

Answer (score 0):

`$.ajax` data should be like following

```
data:{
    "id": id,
    "question": question,
    "answer": answer
}
```

and query use like this

```
$query = "UPDATE ИМЯТАБЛИЦЫ SET QUESTION='$question', ANSWER='$answer' WHERE ID ='$idq'" ;
```

May be it will work..

Comment: сценка "как американские хакеры sql-инъекции внедряли"